# Trying to learn functional mixins

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a calculator function:

```
var Calculator = function(a, b) { 
  this.add = function(a, b) { return a + b; }; 
  this.multiply = function(a, b) { return b * a; }; 
  this.subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b; }; 
  this.divide = function(a, b) { 
    if (a/b === Infinity) {
      return Infinity - Infinity; 
    } else return a/b; 
  }; 
};
```

I want to create a functional mixin for 'sum' (Calculator.sum) so if I pass "1,2,3,4" into it, it will return 10 but not be a property of Calculator

Can someone explain how this can be done?

Comment: It seems that people reading this question don't know what you mean by "functional mixin". Can you clarify where you came across that term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you are talking about the **functional mixin** pattern described [here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/functional-mixins-composing-software-ffb66d5e731c):

```js
const withSum = (object) => {
  return Object.assign({}, object, {
    sum(...args) {
      return args.reduce((sum, number) => sum + number, 0);
    }
  });
};

var Calculator = function(a, b) { 
  this.add = function(a, b) { return a + b; }; 
  this.multiply = function(a, b) { return b * a; }; 
  this.subtract = function(a, b) { return a - b; }; 
  this.divide = function(a, b) { 
    if (a/b === Infinity) {
      return Infinity - Infinity; 
    } else return a/b; 
  }; 
};

var calculator = withSum(new Calculator(1, 2));

console.log('calculator.add(1, 2):', calculator.add(1, 2));
console.log('calculator.multiply(1, 2):', calculator.multiply(1, 2));
console.log('calculator.subtract(2, 1):', calculator.subtract(2, 1));
console.log('calculator.divide(1, 2):', calculator.divide(1, 2));
console.log('calculator.sum(1, 2, 3, 4): ', calculator.sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Note that if your `Calculator.divide` is supposed to return `NaN` if `a/b === Infinity` you can simply write `return NaN;` instead of `Infinity - Infinity` (`NaN` is a global constant).

Also, you can delete the formal parameter list declared in the `Calculator` constructor: `function Calculator() {...}` is sufficient because you never use `a, b`.